# Porting Java classes to the web whilst maintaining all functionality

Tags: java, web-applications, java-web-start

So I have written a few Java classes that take input via the `main` method as passed arguments and then print to the screen. Is there any way I can 'port' this to something I can include in the HTML of a web document? There are multiple classes that work together so I would need some way of including all of these and forcing one specific file to run. For example, if I have `Class1.java` and `Class2.java` I would want to run `Class1.java` but somehow the second class must be included as the first relies on it.

I understand that this is probably not as simple as I'm making it, for example there may be complications with changing `stdout` to use the application screen etc, but anything that can get me started would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understood what you want to do then you could have class2 as member variable and initialize it in constructor of class1 or you can use spring dependency injection

Answer (score 0):

The closest fit to what you are asking for is something called [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface), which is a technology that was popular 15 years ago, but is rarely used now.   The next best fit would be to wrap your classes in something that can run in a java servlet container.

Simply put, instead of taking arguments in on the main method, you would accept them as URL parameters.  Instead of printing to stdout, you would print to a special stream that sends the content over a socket to a web browser.  There are many fine tutorials on the web for creating servlets.   I like this one:  http://helloworldprograms.blogspot.com/2010/08/servlet-hello-world.html